# How to pass a uniqueidentifier param to a stored procedure in SSRS Report Builder?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I need my data in SSRS to come from a stored procedure taking one parameter, a uniqueidentifier. In my data source in Report Builder, I get a correct test connection.

In my data set, I tell SSRS to use a stored procedure (named "ReportQuery" in this case), and add the correct value in the "Parameters" tab, chosen from the left-side menu. However, when I run the report, no data shows up - nothing. No error messages, either.
If I go to the Query Designer and change the value to "Text", I can write the call to the stored procedure and add the parameter and then, executing this by clicking the "Run" icon (exclamation point), I see the data correctly in the lower pane of the Query Designer. So this works in the Query Designer.

```
ReportQuery @CompanyId = '59270CA0-8AC7-4D2C-BC9C-1088BC8186F2'
```

Obviously I need to determine this parameter at runtime, but I'm not even dealing with that yet.

Leaving this set to "Text" with the same value, unchanged, and running the report, again I get nothing - no data. I expect that the data that shows up in Query Designer would show up here.

Obviously I'm making a rookie mistake - does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: It's been a minute but what happens when you convert that string to lowercase?
ReportQuery @CompanyId = Lower('59270CA0-8AC7-4D2C-BC9C-1088BC8186F2')

Comment: I get a syntax error - "Incorrect syntax near '59270CA0-8AC7-4D2C-BC9C-1088BC8186F2'.

Comment: If you're getting no data then the dataset returned no rows; we can't see your query but sounds like you're passing a value for a parameter where no rows match that parameter.

Comment: Although it does sound that way, it works in Query Designer. The parameter passed in definitely works in SSMS, too.

Comment: What happens when you don't use the lower to do it?
`'59270ca0-8ac7-4d2c-bc9c-1088bc8186f2'`
For some reason, I recall it comparing in lowercase for me before

Comment: There's no difference - still works in Query Designer, but not in the main report.

Comment: It could be caching, try hitting the refresh button on the report toolbar after the empty report has loaded. If that does not work, try changing your dataset query to text and doing something like `EXEC ReportQuery  '59270CA0-8AC7-4D2C-BC9C-1088BC8186F2'`.

Comment: Is it possible that the Query Designer, running locally on your computer, has its data source referencing a different SQL Server than the data source on the deployed SSRS server?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning nope - only one SQL server here.